# How to authenticate user by php to use it's drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

At the moment I am trying to find out how to use my Google Drive to store images.
I don't want any user interaction. Users access my web-application then upload files and these files should be stored in my Google drive.

1. I figured out service account. It works fine, no user interaction. The only problem is storage limit and it is not possible to buy extra to extend it. So we can not use it.
2. Web application type where I provide redirect URI, sends me code to authenticate to use Drive API. BUT to receive code user should be authenticated and after that I receive code which will allow me to use users Google drive. But here I want to receive code by my account and store images in my Drive.

How can I get rid off user authentication, but use php authentication with my credentials (myaccount@gmail.com) and store files in my drive.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a stackoverflow question but more geared for Google Drive forums / support systems.  Stackoverflow is about specific coding issues.

Comment: I hope that somebody may provide code to overpass user authentication